# Frequency of the Prime Numbers

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose I took all natural numbers less than or equal to $x$ and I picked one at random. Is there a way that we know of to express the probability that my number is prime in terms of $x$, for all $x$?

For example, for $x=12$, the prime numbers less than or equal to $x$ are $2,3,5,7$ and $11$, so my probability is $5/12$.

Answer (score 28):

There is no explicit formula, but the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) says that as $x$ tends to infinity, there are around $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ primes $≤ x$.

This means that the chance that a random number is prime will be around $\frac{x}{\ln x} \cdot \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{\ln x}$.

Comment: In OPs example, 1/ln(12) = 0.40 while 5/12 = 0.42.

Comment: infinity is a bit further

Comment: @infinitezero The formula is not exact – I said the chance will *be around* that number. (By the way, this answer is blowing up!)

Comment: I know. I just pointed out that even for small X it's pretty close.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is the chance that a random number _selected from the set_ $\{1,...,x\}$ will be prime.

Comment: In fact, this approximation can be improved to $\mathrm{Li}(x) = \int_2^x\frac{1}{\log t}dt$. What's more, the Riemann hypothesis implies that this improved estimate is very accurate, within $\frac{\sqrt x \log x}{8\pi}$ of the actual value for $x$ large enough ($\ge 2657$; this is result 6.18 in "Sharper Bounds for the Chebyshev Functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$. II", Lowell Schoenfeld, 1976, which can be found at https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-134/S0025-5718-1976-0457374-X/S0025-5718-1976-0457374-X.pdf ).

Comment: Plenty more on this subject can be found by Googling "Riemann Hypothesis and distribution of primes", for example in the answers to this Quora question: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relationship-between-the-Riemann-Hypothesis-and-prime-numbers

Comment: @probably_someone True but it's redundant since there's [no uniform distribution on the integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247984/what-is-the-probability-distribution-on-integers).

Comment: @Jam Well, the statement as posed in the original answer doesn't really have a well-defined meaning without that addition, so I disagree that it's redundant.

Comment: @probably_someone: that is wrong. $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is _approximately_ equal to the chance etc. (You can make this statement more precise, as Robin Saunders' comment says.)